# LS_COLORS key for network shared directories

Tags: bash, unix, ls

I have mounted a network share with NFS and when I do `ls --color` it highlights the directories with green which is very hard to see. What LS_COLORS key do I have to change to change the highlight color? Also once this is done do I have to add something to my bashrc so that this takes effect on every login?

Comment: A little late to the party, but I created an [LS_COLORS Generator](http://jordanarseno.com/LS_COLORS) for folks that happen to come across this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'be finally figured this out and I needed to edit the OPEN_WRITABLE flag in the dircolors. To do this I followed these steps:

1. execute the following from your home dir `dircolors -p .dircolors`
2. then edit the file ~/.dircolors and update OPEN_WRITABLE with the desired colors
3. edit ~/.bashrc and add the following

   ```
   # enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
   if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
       test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
       [ -e "$HOME/.dircolors" ] && DIR_COLORS="$HOME/.dircolors"
       [ -e "$DIR_COLORS" ] || DIR_COLORS=""
           eval "`dircolors -b $DIR_COLORS`"
           alias ls='ls --color=auto' 
           alias grep='grep --color=auto'
           alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
           alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
   fi
   ```
4. run `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Why evaluate the output of dircolors -b twice? Why test for the existence of .dircolors three times? There seems to be the case where, if DIR_COLORS is predefined AND .dircolors does not exist, then the parent declared DIR_COLORS file is replaces the first evaluation. The alias declarations implies that LS_COLORS affects grep, but grep uses GREP_COLORS which does not seem to be defined during the eval of dircolors -b.

Answer (score 1):

This is the command to get current LS_COLORS

```
dircolors --print-database
```

If no mistaken, NFS is considered as BD (block device driver)

If you want to override the existing green color for network drive for every login,
declare something like below in your .bashrc

```
LS_COLORS="bd=xx;yy" <-- color can refer back dircolors --print-database
export LS_COLORS
```

Comment: no luck (trying on my cifs mounted drive this time if that makes a diff) I have bd=34;40 which is foreground blue, background black

Comment: remounted without write permissions on directories which has removed the highlight color

Comment: Did you `source ~/.bashrc` after the saved the changes? Otherwise, consider this `EXEC 01;32`, <-- originally EXEC is green

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by changing the values for 'tw' STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE and 'ow' OTHER_WRITABLE in env var LS_COLORS.

have a look at [Configuring LS_COLORS](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors)

```
:tw=00;34:ow=00;34:
```